# Difference Between two dates or N/A

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, case

I have a calculation between two dates.

What I'm trying to do is if the start date is before 03/07/20 then show N/A otherwise the difference between the two dates

```
case 
when StartDate < cast('03-07-20' as date) then
'N/A'
else 
DATEDIFF(day,  cast(StartDate as date), cast(SwabDate as date) )
end 
as Days_From_First
```

I get

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N/A' to data type int.
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

All branches of a `case` expression must return the same datatype, so you can't have a branch return a string (`'NA'`) and the other a integer (as returned by `datediff()`). What happens when you do that is that SQL Server prioritizes the numeric datatype, and hence attempts to coerce `'NA'` to an integer - which fails.

You *could* cast the return value of `datediff()` to a string - but I would not recommend that. Probably, using `null` is the best way to go here: in SQL, that's usually how we represent the absence of data:

```
case when StartDate >= '20200703'
    then datediff(day, cast(startdate as date), cast(swabdate as date))
end as Days_From_First
```

Note that I changed the date comparison to use literal `'20200703'`, that SQL Server is able to unambiguously understand as a date in format `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the results to be strings:

```
(case when StartDate < cast('2020-03-07' as date)
      then 'N/A'
      else convert(varchar(255), datediff(day, cast(StartDate as date), cast(SwabDate as date) ))
 end) as Days_From_First
```

That said, I would really suggest that you forget about `'N/A'` and just use `NULL`.

Also, I don't know if your date is 2020-03-07 or 2020-07-03.  That is why you should use standard date formats.